# GestureDetetector doesn't work what can I do?

Tags: flutter, dart, button, gesturedetector, gesture-detection

Imagine a button called from the butcontainer class and a button created in the project class, when the button created in the project class is clicked, the gesture detector used text is displayed on the screen, while the button called from the butcontainer class works properly but does not react on the screen.
[its my butcontainer class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I2F4.png)
[its my text class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8VuV.png)
[its called my text class (in project class)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BhR0.png)
[the top is my button called from the class, the bottom is my button created in the project class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2rH7.png)

I have no idea what to do please help

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code as text rather than an image

Answer (score 0):

Your `gesture detector` is not working because you have not included any `callbacks` in `gesture detector`.

It will work when you will include `onTap` or `onLongPress` like this

```
GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){},
              child: Container(child: Text("click me"),
   ),
),
```

it will work when you will include callbacks in it.

Comment: thanks for reply but it didn't work

Comment: what you want to achieve

Comment: gesture detector dont show the ripple effect if you want the ripple effect use InkWell widget

Comment: Not an effect its my first project calculator. I want if I click a button the text willl change